# box2d crashes small polygon

Tags: java, box2d

Im trying to cut bodys in my world. My code is based off [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/06/25/slicing-splitting-and-cutting-objects-with-box2d-part-2/). But when the new polygon shape is very small i get this error.

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\java.exe   
File: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/libgdx/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/jni/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp, Line 158

Expression: false
```

Below is my code to create the new body

```java
 private void creatBody(Array<Vector2> vs){
        if (vs.size >= 8){
            System.out.println("Vectors = " + vs.size);
        }
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();

        Vector2 centre = findCentroid(vs, vs.size);
        if (Float.isInfinite(centre.x) || Float.isNaN(centre.x) || (Float.isInfinite(centre.y) || Float.isNaN(centre.y))){
            System.out.println("centre : " + centre.toString());
            return;
        }

        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(centre.x, centre.y);

        Vector2[] v = new Vector2[vs.size];
        // System.out.println("Vectors");
        for (int i = 0; i < vs.size; i++) {
            // System.out.println("pre : " + vs.get(i).toString());
            v[i] = new Vector2(vs.get(i).x * PPM, vs.get(i).y  * PPM);
            v[i].sub(centre);
            // System.out.println("aft : " + v[i].toString());
        }
        System.out.println("pre");
        shape.set(v);
        System.out.println("after");

        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = 1;
        Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
        for (int i = 0; i<vs.size; i++) {
            v[i].add(centre);
        }
    }


    private Vector2 findCentroid(Array<Vector2> vs, int count) {
        Vector2 c = new Vector2();
        float area = 0.0f;
        float p1X = 0.0f;
        float p1Y = 0.0f;
        float inv3 = 1.0f / 3.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            Vector2 p2 = vs.get(i);
            Vector2 p3;
            if (i + 1 < count){
                p3 = vs.get(i + 1);
            }else{
                p3 = vs.get(0);
            }
            float e1X = p2.x - p1X;
            float e1Y = p2.y - p1Y;
            float e2X = p3.x - p1X;
            float e2Y = p3.y - p1Y;
            float D = (e1X * e2Y - e1Y * e2X);
            float triangleArea = 0.5f*D;
            area += triangleArea;
            c.x += triangleArea * inv3 * (p1X + p2.x + p3.x);
            c.y += triangleArea * inv3 * (p1Y + p2.y + p3.y);
        }
        c.x*=1.0/area;
        c.y*=1.0/area;
        return new Vector2(c.x * PPM, c.y * PPM);
    }
```

And these are the vertices i got from cutting. But it crashes on these vertices So i made this peace of code to test it for easier replication.

```
    Array<Vector2> verts = new Array<Vector2>();
    verts.add(new Vector2(0.022f,0.015407243f));
    verts.add(new Vector2(0.0020000006f,0.015407243f));
    verts.add(new Vector2(0.022000004f,0.015f));
    verts.add(new Vector2(0.0020000006f,0.015f));
    creatBody(verts);
```

I searched for the error and what i could find is that my polygonShape is to small.

Comment: Correct, it is too small. Make it bigger.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D is it possible to change something that it would allow small shapes? [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/06/25/slicing-splitting-and-cutting-objects-with-box2d-part-2/). It is possible to make realy small shapes. (I know its not in java).

Comment: No, it's not. That limit is set for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

## Index: Box2D/Box2D/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp

open b2PolygonShape.cpp and apply this patch

```
//if (b2DistanceSquared(v, ps[j]) < 0.5f * b2_linearSlop)   
if (b2DistanceSquared(v, ps[j]) < ((0.5f * b2_linearSlop) * (0.5f * b2_linearSlop)))
```